# Uniformly bound exists for a continuous function sequence in a neighbhorhood of a convergent point?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Assume that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_0) < \infty$$ and also that $\forall n\ge1$, $f_n(x)$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $x_0$, say $(x_0-\delta_1, x_0+\delta_1)$. 
Besides, for any fixed $x$ in the above neighborhood, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) < \infty.$$
Show that there exists a number $N>0$ and $0<\delta_2<\delta_1$ such that when $n>N$, we have $|f_n(x)|$ is uniformly bounded in $(x_0-\delta_2,x_0+\delta_2)$.

For example, let
$$
f_n(x)=\frac{2n^{1-x}-1-x}{2n^{1-x}-3+x}
$$
$x_0=1$, and $x>0$.
We can show $f_n(x_0)$ has a finite limit.

Comment: Sorry, but, I'm afraid that, as stated, this is false. Consider the sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ s.t. $f_n(x)=nx^2$ and $x_0=0$. Then for all $n$ we have $f_n(x_0)=0$, hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_0)=0$. However this sequence isn't uniformly bounded in any neighbourhood of 0.

Comment: @NateRiver, what if add another condition $lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)<\infty$ for any fixed $x\in (x_0-\delta_1,x_0+\delta_1)$?

Comment: In this case, I think the result is still false. Consider $x_0=0$, and the sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ s.t.
$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
n^2x & x\in[0,\frac{1}{n}]\\
2n-n^2x & x\in]\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
This sequence converges pointwise to 0, yet it is not uniformly bounded on any neighbourhood of 0.

Comment: @NateRiver  do you know how to make it hold by adding some additonal condition? Is my example uniformly bounded in a neighborhood of x=1? Thanks.

Comment: @RRL, I am not sure why your proof is wrong, could you give me a hint?

Comment: @Harry:  I reposted my answer and tried to clarify -- proving a weaker result.

Comment: @RRL, I find that Nate River's example is still pointwise bounded and satisfied with your condition. I think you want to construct a sequence of closed intervals, but that is a minor issue. But I still cannot see why his example violates your proof.

Comment: @RRL your second paragraph said: for example ..., $|f_n(1/2)|\le 2$ for all $n$..  It is bounded for x=1/2.  I do not know why you give such an example.